# Typescript 5 minute tutorial with angular2 breaks on get

Tags: typescript, angular, typescript1.8

I am attempting to understand typscript and angular2 by following the https://angular.io/guide/quickstart.

I went through the various steps but the last step `npm start` result in the following errors

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

J:\workspace\epimss\typescript\angular2-quickstart>npm start

> angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start J:\workspace\epimss\typescript\angular2-quickstart
> concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite"

[0] 
[0] > angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 tsc:w J:\workspace\epimss\typescript\angular2-quickstart
[0] > tsc -w
[0] 
[1] 
[1] > angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 lite J:\workspace\epimss\typescript\angular2-quickstart
[1] > lite-server
[1] 
[0] 7:51:31 PM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
[1] Did not detect a `bs-config.json` or `bs-config.js` override file. Using lite-server defaults...
[1] ** browser-sync options **
[1] { injectChanges: false,
[1]   files: [ './**/*.{html,htm,css,js}' ],
[1]   server: { baseDir: './', middleware: [ [Function], [Function] ] } }
[1] [BS] Access URLs:
[1]  ------------------------------------
[1]        Local: http://localhost:3000
[1]     External: http://192.168.2.4:3000
[1]  ------------------------------------
[1]           UI: http://localhost:3001
[1]  UI External: http://192.168.2.4:3001
[1]  ------------------------------------
[1] [BS] Serving files from: ./
[1] [BS] Watching files...
[1] 16.03.09 19:51:36 404 GET /index.html
[1] 16.03.09 19:51:37 404 GET /favicon.ico
[1] 16.03.09 19:51:38 404 GET /favicon.ico
```

Has anyone has a similar experience?

Thanks

Comment: I don't actually see any server error here aside from the Not Found error which is a client error anyways, which with the current information you gave is impossible to figure out the root cause. It makes me want to ask the question if your index.html file exists in the right location or if you started the npm server from the directory containing it?

Comment: You are correct Corvus. The index.html was in the app folder, NOT in the root folder. Moving it to the root folder and running the command displayed the web page.

Comment: Could you provide the structure of your project (folder, files, ...)? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

After you finish the tutorial you will get a folder structure like in the picture below, now for lite-server to serve from **app** and **node_modules** folders you need to add a **bs-config.json** file in angular2-quickstart folder.

[image]

```
{
  "port": 3000,
  "files": ["/app/**/*.{html,htm,css,js}"],
  "server": { "baseDir": ["./app"],
              "routes": {
                  "/node_modules": "node_modules" , "/app": "app", "/app.component": "app"
              }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[1] [BS] Serving files from: ./
```

Followed by

```
[1] 16.03.09 19:51:36 404 GET /index.html
[1] 16.03.09 19:51:37 404 GET /favicon.ico
```

Just means that those files (`index.html`, `favicon.ico`) are not in that location (`./`).

You'll need to browse to the location that does contain those files, or move those files to the location you are browsing.